# SQL Server stored procedure becomes slow after some time

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have created a stored procedure in SQL Server which returns data in one second. This stored procedure works fine for a couple of days, and it becomes slow later on. However if I re-execute it without making changes, it becomes fast.

I came to know that `Recompile` may fix this issue. Any suggestion on this?

Also will `ReCompile` cause any performance issue as this query is hit almost every second?

Comment: have you tried by update the statitics?

Comment: Your question is missing many details that would enable some initial analysis. For instance: Where is the returned data coming from? (it appears to be safe to assume that it is extracted from tables, but what tables and how are they organized); Besides selecting, what is the SP doing? How big is the returned data? .....

Comment: Also actual execution plans for fast and slow times are needed.

Comment: My SP is selecting data from multiple tables and it stores in local temporary table and selects from it. amount of data in temporary table is around 300 only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Also will ReCompile cause any performance issue as this query is hit at almost every second ?

Yes recompiling takes toll on CPU resources.Even though compiling a query plan is done in a matter of milliseconds,this will add extra CPU burden since query wont't use existing query plan

> I came to know that Recomplie may fix this issue ?

SQL server will store the query plan with the parameter passed and optimize the plan for this input..

Suppose you have a table with each customer having approximately equal orders,then recompiling every time wont help you..

On the other hand if your customer's orders distribution is uneven,in range of 1-10000.In this case if SP is compiled using input of customer having one order,then when 10000 orders customer is passed through SQL will underestimate memory and may spill to tempdb ..

There are many ways in which you can overcome [parameter sniffing](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/08/t-sql-queries/parameter-sniffing-embedding-and-the-recompile-options),try to read the link i referred and see which option works for you